# SPA project structure that works in Visual Studio 2015 and VS Code

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I have just taken over a large LOB AngularJs mvc + webapi application. it's a spa where there homecontroller return the index and start the angular app thats resides in the app folder.

My question is how do I organise the package? And what packages managers do I use?

I am thinking of using nuget for the server side packages and npm + bower for the client. Placing all client packages in the app folder including type definition for typescript.

I am using gulp for the build.

All input are valid and much appreciated.

Comment: If you are planning to move to Angular2, I suggest you take a look at SystemJS and JSPM (http://jspm.io/) That means no more *bower*.